# Multipart file uploading in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter-web

Is there any way to multi-part upload file to the server for Flutter Web natively. Because there so many ways to do it for flutter iOS and Android.

Answer (score 5):

For Android/IOS we are using:

```
    multiPFile = await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path,
          filename: file.name, contentType: MediaType.parse(mimeType));
```

For Web you need to build a MultiPartFile from the bytes of the file:

```
    multiPFile = await MultipartFile.fromBytes(file.bytes,
          filename: file.name, contentType: MediaType.parse(mimeType));
```

Comment: How to upload an image and list of images in flutter web. I am getting path errors in it